# Error : while start Apache nutch with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache, nutch

when i try to run, following error comes, In mongodb logs one connection accepted and end immediately.how solve it?
 
    $ bin/crawl conf/urls/seeds.txt tuto 1
    No SOLRURL specified. Skipping indexing.
    Injecting seed URLs
    /e/apache-nutch/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject conf/urls/seeds.txt -crawlId tuto
    InjectorJob: starting at 2016-10-01 18:15:14
    InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: conf/urls/seeds.txt
    InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore as the Gora storage class.
    InjectorJob: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:774)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:646)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:434)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:281)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:125)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:348)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
            at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:115)
            at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:231)
            at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
            at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
            at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the newest version of Nutch uses

```
# bin/nutch inject seedDirectory/
```

This worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just removing two lines i.e.:

```
[field name="sitemaps" docfield="sitemaps" type="document"]
```

and

```
[field name="stmPriority" docfield="stmPriority" type="int32"]
```

from `gora-mongodb-mapping.xml` file in `conf` folder of nutch. Hope it will help you..